# fetch the stand alone database details who are part of our subscription but not under any elastic pool

Tags: azure-resource-manager

We are having databases under same resource group. Some are stand alone azure PaaS service and some are under elastic pool. the database creation is through script. We want to fetch the stand alone database details who are part of our  subscription but not under any elastic pool using power shell script. Is it practically possible?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/?view=azps-2.5.0

We want to fetch the stand alone database details who are part of our  subscription but not under any elastic pool using power shell script. Is it practically possible?

Comment: Any update this issue? Could it solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Try the script as below, it works on my side.

```
$sqlservers = Get-AzSqlServer
foreach($item in $sqlservers){
    Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $item.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $item.ServerName | Where-Object {$_.SkuName -ne 'ElasticPool'}
}
```

The script above get the databases(whose resource type is `Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases`) in your whole subscription, if you just want to get the databases in one resource group, add the `-ResourceGroupName` to the first line.

```
$sqlservers = Get-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName <resource group name>
```

---

Besides, the resource type of `DataWarehouse` is also `Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases`, the script also gets them. I am not sure the database you mean includes it or not, if you don't want to get `DataWarehouse` , change the script like below.

```
$sqlservers = Get-AzSqlServer 
foreach($item in $sqlservers){
    Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $item.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $item.ServerName | Where-Object {$_.SkuName -ne 'ElasticPool' -and $_.SkuName -ne 'DataWarehouse'}
}
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)